# How can I flag a question which belongs to askubuntu.com

Tags: support, flags, scope, stack-exchange

From time to time, I see questions which clearly belong to askubuntu.com. E.g. "How to install foo on Ubuntu baa". When trying to flag as off topic -> belong to another page of network I don't have the opportunity to choose askubuntu (or much other pages of the network). Is there a special way to flag such questions?